# How to send email with signature gmail api

Tags: gmail-api, signature

I'm trying to get the Signature that is in Gmail, how can I achieve this?

Gmail API is lack of content for Javascript. Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean your signature or the signature from an incoming message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to obtain your own signature, here is a sample:

```
gmail.users.settings.sendAs.get({
userId: 'me',
auth: jwtClient,
sendAsEmail: 'paste your email',
fields: 'signature'
}, function (err, resp) {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(resp);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you.
I found out this:

```
gapi.client.request({path: `https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/${user_info.id}/settings/sendAs/${user_info.emails[0].value}`}).then((data) => {
    var d = JSON.parse(data.body);
    signature = d.signature;
});
```